# Func<dynamic, HelperResult> returning empty string on razor page

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages, razorengine

I am not sure what the issue is here but the `Request.RawUrl` is always blank. If I just put a random string in, it works `@<text>ddd</text>`, but any variables doesnt.  Am I missing something?

```
 <form class="clearfix" action="@this.RenderSection("FormUrl", @<text>@(Request.RawUrl.ToString();)</text>)"


public static HelperResult RenderSection(this WebPageBase webPage, string name, Func<dynamic, HelperResult> defaultContents)
        {
            if (webPage.IsSectionDefined(name))
            {
                return webPage.RenderSection(name);
            }
            return defaultContents(null);
        }
```

**Output**

```
<form class="clearfix" action=""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inline setup just wouldnt work so I tried the below and it worked.

```
var action = this.RenderSection("FormUrl", @<text>@Html.Raw(Request.RawUrl)</text>).ToHtmlString();

<form class="clearfix" action="@action"
```